# Output multiple pandas DataFrames to CSV with custom name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to output multiple csvs from a function - but also name the csv per the name of the `df`.

```
dfs = ( df1, df2 , df3 , df4)

for df in dfs:

    def to_csvs(df, 'df name as csv name'):
        df.to_csv('example.csv')
        return df
```

I want to use a loop to feed in my multiple `dfs` and have a parameter in the function input that would name the `csv` output as well - is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, I recommend not defining a function inside a for-loop. Do it outside and then call the function inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize the CSV names you could store your DFs in a dict with the key as the CSV name, e.g.:

```
dfs = {"df1 name":df1, "df2 name":df2}  # ..etc

for k, v in dfs.items():
    v.to_csv('./{}.csv'.format(k)))
```